# Create trigger in PhpMyadmin?

Tags: mysql, triggers

I am using two tables.

User  table contains the firstname and lastname field and contactinfo is another table contain the field called 'Name' with usertable Id.

I want to make a trigger  whenever the User tables firstname or lastname is updated. I want change this contactinfo's Name to whatever they changed in the User table. Is it possible through trigger?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The general syntax of CREATE TRIGGER is :

```
CREATE TRIGGER trigger_name trigger_time trigger_event ON tbl_name 
FOR EACH ROW trigger_statement
```

Take a look at examples from http://www.roseindia.net/mysql/mysql5/triggers.shtml and http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/create-trigger.html